# IOS: GLSL in In-App-Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, glsl

Is it possible for us to include GLSL inside In-App-Purchase?? I have a game idea to sell game level with special genre, which will be nice to have a special visual treatment for that. And since it is episodic, we have to put the GLSL in the level itself.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and I have not developed any iOS apps besides some fiddling), iOS and it's system libraries supports compiling OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL at runtime.  This link would seem to confirm that:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW3

GLSL is just text.  I can't think of a good reason you couldn't load text from an In-App-Purchase to do what you want with it. Now, if you wanted to obfuscate it so it's not obvious in an iOS device backup, well that's another issue.  (I'm speaking hypothetically here... I'm not sure what the recommended practices are for In App Purchases, and some of those practices might cover that issue.)